# Web Push API: getting unique identifier when handling the pushsubscriptionchange event

Tags: push-notification, service-worker, web-push

I've been struggling with the following challenge for quite long and couldn't find a proper solution.

I need to send a unique ID to the server when my service worker handles the pushsubscriptionchange event.

I have a unique ID stored in a cookie but SW can't access cookies, I was trying to use the Cache API to pass that info to the SW but it doesn't seem like the right way.

I'm open to hear new ideas/solutions to tackle this challenge.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this problem is using IndexedDB. It is available in the Service Worker context.

You can use [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage), which makes using IndexedDB really simple.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was thinking of using.
Store the device ID just after I register the SW and then pull it when I need it in the SW (handling the event)